# Best Grasshopper plugin to analyse floor plans

Tags: analysis, rhino, grasshopper

I'm trying to figure out the best way to analyse a grasshopper/rhino floor plan. I am trying to create a room map to determine how many doors it takes to reach an exit in a residential building. The inputs are the room curves, names and doors.
I have tried to use space syntax or SYNTACTIC, but some of the components are missing. Alot of the plugins I have been looking at are good at creating floor plans but not analysing them.

 
 Your help would be greaty appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create some sort of spine that goes through the rooms that passes only through doors, and do some path finding across the topology counting how many "hops" you need to reach the exit.

So one way to get the topology is to create a data structure (a tuple, keyValuePair) that holds the curve (room) and a point (the door), now loop each room to each other and see if the point/door of each of the rooms is closer than some threshold, if it is, store the relationship as a graph (in the abstract sense you don't really need to make lines out of it, but if you plan to use other plugins for path-finding, this can be useful), then run some path-finding (Dijkstra's, A*, etc...) to find the shortest distance.

As for SYNTACTIC: If copying the GHA after unblocking from the installation path to the special components folder (or pointing the folder from _GrasshopperDeveloperSettings) doesn't work, tick the Memory load *.GHA assemblies using COFF byte arrays option of the _GrasshopperDeveloperSettings. 
*Note that SYNTACTIC won't give you any automatic topology.

If you need some pseudo-code just write a comment and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you! I found a different download link for SYNTACTIC on https://sites.google.com/site/pirouznourian/syntactic-design  which has all the components on it.

Comment: Glad I could help